# How to send instant email with mail chimp in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to find MailChimp documentation for implementing iOS app that sends instant email to user just like SendGrid. But I can't details about send instant email using email templates via MailChimp even I don't know was it possible or not. How to send instant email to receiver through mail chimp email templates? Any link or suggestion. Thanking you!

For reference I added Sample code sending email via SendGrid:

```
let dictionary: [String: Any] = [

            "personalizations" :[
                [
                    "to":[
                        [
                            "email": Constants.feedbackEmail,
                            "name": Constants.feedbackEmailUser
                        ]
                    ],

                    "dynamic_template_data": [ //Dynamic data to apply email body

                        "sender_name": name,
                        "subject":subject,
                        "content":content,
                        "type":type
                    ]
                ]
            ],

            "from" :[
                "email": Constants.feedbackEmail,
                "name": Constants.feedbackEmailUser
            ],

            "reply_to":[
                "email": Constants.feedbackEmail,
                "name": Constants.feedbackEmailUser
            ],
             "template_id": "d-7336fe13346e82434596ed08b023529"
        ]

//TODO:- Calling POST method URL with body data of this JSON object.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send instant transactional emails to your users you have to use [Mandrill](https://mandrill.com/), which is the transactional tool of Mailchimp made exactly for your use case.
You will be able to create your templates in Mailchimp and use them in Mandrill.

Comment: Wow thank you! I can't login by using Mailchimp account in Mandrill. Does mandrill  need premium plan?

Comment: Yes I believe that you need to upgrade your Mailchimp plan to have access to Mandrill.